# Graphql server not starting using Graphql kickstart Java

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java

this is my first question and I'm really stuck, so any help is really appreciated!

I'm trying to create a GraphQL server using [GraphQL Kickstart Java](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/spring-boot/) and Spring Boot 3. It needs to be a mix of REST and Graphql. I've followed the instructions mentioned in the documentation but I can't seem to be able to start the GraphQL server, Postman cannot connect to graphql server at `http://localhost:8080/graphql`.

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.0"
        mavenBom "com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-dependencies:13.0.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:13.0.0'


    // testing facilities
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter-test:13.0.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And here's my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url:
    username:
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

jwt:
  secret:
  expiration-time:

graphql:
  servlet:
    enabled: true
  playground:
    enabled: true
    cdn:
      enabled: false
      version: latest
  altair:
    enabled: true
    cdn:
      enabled: false
      version: 4.0.2
    options:
      initial-settings:
        theme: dracula
      endpoint-url: /graphql
```

Also, the playground is also not accessible, throwing 404 error. Any hint on what I might be missing that the server is not starting?

I wish to have a mix of GraphQL server and REST API. With current implementation, REST API is working, but GraphQL server doesn't seem to start. Any help?